# shell script arguments non positional

Tags: shell

Is there a way to feed non positional arguments to a shell script?
Meaning explicitly specify some kind of flag?

```
. myscript.sh value1 value2
. myscript.sh -val1=value1 -val2=value2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getopts`, but I don't like it because it's complicated to use and it doesn't support long option names (not the POSIX version anyway).

I recommend against using environment variables.  There's just too much risk of name collision.  For example, if your script reacts differently depending on the value of the `ARCH` environment variable, and it executes another script that (unbeknownst to you) also reacts to the `ARCH` environment variable, then you probably have a hard-to-find bug that only shows up occasionally.

This is the pattern I use:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 [options] [--] [file...]

Arguments:

  -h, --help
    Display this usage message and exit.

  -f <val>, --foo <val>, --foo=<val>
    Documentation goes here.

  -b <val>, --bar <val>, --bar=<val>
    Documentation goes here.

  --
    Treat the remaining arguments as file names.  Useful if the first
    file name might begin with '-'.

  file...
    Optional list of file names.  If the first file name in the list
    begins with '-', it will be treated as an option unless it comes
    after the '--' option.
EOF
}

# handy logging and error handling functions
log() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
error() { log "ERROR: $*" >&2; }
fatal() { error "$*"; exit 1; }
usage_fatal() { error "$*"; usage >&2; exit 1; }

# parse options
foo="foo default value goes here"
bar="bar default value goes here"
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    arg=$1
    case $1 in
        # convert "--opt=the value" to --opt "the value".
        # the quotes around the equals sign is to work around a
        # bug in emacs' syntax parsing
        --*'='*) shift; set -- "${arg%%=*}" "${arg#*=}" "$@"; continue;;
        -f|--foo) shift; foo=$1;;
        -b|--bar) shift; bar=$1;;
        -h|--help) usage; exit 0;;
        --) shift; break;;
        -*) usage_fatal "unknown option: '$1'";;
        *) break;; # reached the list of file names
    esac
    shift || usage_fatal "option '${arg}' requires a value"
done
# arguments are now the file names
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is pass them as environment variables:

```
$ val1=value1 val2=value2 ./myscript.sh
```

This doesn't work with csh variants, but you can use env if you are using such a shell.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. The name is getopts http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/getopts.1.asp

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts d:x arg
do
        case "$arg" in
                d) darg="$OPTARG";;
                x) xflag=1;;
                ?) echo >&2 "Usage: $0 [-x] [-d darg] files ..."; exit 1;;
        esac
done
shift $(( $OPTIND-1 ))

for file
do
        echo =$file=
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Script has arguments as follows:
 - $0 - script name
-  $1, $2, $3.... - received arguments
$* = all arguments,
$# = number of arguments

Reference:
http://famulatus.com/ks/os/solaris/item/203-arguments-in-sh-scripts.html